# Key error while adding a new key to the dictionary

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary, keyerror

This is my code:

```
nums = sorted(nums)
n = len(nums)
maps = { 0 : [nums[0]]}
maps[2] = ["shot"]
dp = [1 for _ in nums]

for i in range(1 , n):
    for j in range(i , -1 , -1):
        if nums[i] % nums[j] == 0:
            dp[i] = dp[j]+1
            print(maps)
            if i not in maps.keys():
                maps[i] = maps[j].append(nums[i])
```

The error message:

```
    KeyError: 1
    maps[i] = maps[j].append(nums[i])
    Line 15 in largestDivisibleSubset (Solution.py)
    ret = Solution().largestDivisibleSubset(param_1)
    Line 41 in _driver (Solution.py)
    _driver()
    Line 52 in <module> (Solution.py)
```

The input: `nums = [1,2,3,5,7]`

Comment: Aside from the key error, you do realize that `maps[j].append(nums[i])` returns None?

Comment: You should probably explain a bit more what you're trying to do, and what output you would expect given the input.

Comment: On the first iteration, `j == i == 1`.  `i` is not in `maps` but then `maps[j]` *also* won't be in maps, hence the `KeyError`.  I have no idea what algorithm you are implementing so you'll have to explain yourself if you want a fix.

Answer (score 0):

You can only use the append method to insert a value to a key, that is already existing.
So either you do something like this:

`maps[i] = nums[i]`

Or:

`maps[i] = nums[j]`

Answer (score 0):

This is your problem stanza:

```
if i not in maps.keys():
  maps[i] = maps[j].append(nums[i])
```

Here you are asking 'if i is not in the maps dictionary, then get the value at index i from the nums array and append it to the value referenced by the key j in the maps dictionary, then assign the result of that function back to the value of the key i in the dictionary'.

`append()` returns `None`, which means you'll just be putting `None` at the key `i`. But your error is actually saying that the key `1` doesn't exist in the object you're looking into. Presumably that is `maps`, because you are attempting to dereference `maps[j]` - and `j` is not one of the keys in `maps`. Since that can't be fetched, and would be `None` if you did, you can't append anything to it.

A definitive solution can't be given here, since it's unclear what you want to end up with. Given an input array of `[1,2,3,5,7]` what do you expect `maps` to look like at the end of this function?

One thing that might help is something like:

```
if i not in maps.keys():
    ls = maps.get(j, [])
    ls.append(nums[i])
    maps[i] = ls
```

Here, we get the list at index `j` and return a default empty list `[]` if `j` is not inside the map already. Then we assign the modified list to the key `i`. I'm not sure if this is actually what you're looking for, though.